# AWS elastic transcoder does not add the watermark text

Tags: amazon-web-services, media, aws-elastictranscoder

I trying to join the multiple videos in AWS elastic transcoder. All things are working as expected. But I couldn't add the water text in every video. But, I am able to add the watermark logo for all videos.

I am trying with SCC files also. That was also not working.

My Requirement is, I need to add subtitles for all the videos.

Is Aws elastic transcoder providing an option for this?

[image]

I need to add subtitles like the above image.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

AWS Transcoder has an option called **'Captions'**.
You can configure Elastic Transcoder to transcode captions, or subtitles, from one format to another.
Please refer the below link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/captions.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have created .scc files. But I did not get any result.

Comment: 00:00:00:01 496e f1d3 e3f2 e962 e520 f7ef f26b 7320 ef6e 20cd 61e3 20ef f220 57e9 6e64 eff7 73ae